# How to restore brew formula after I rm it

Tags: macos, boost, homebrew

I just `rm` a formula in `tap homebrew/homebrew-core` which is `boost-python` and `boost` since they seem to be broken. I want to delete them and **retap** them again.

What I have tried:
`brew tap --repair` and `brew tap homebrew/homebrew-core`

But they didn't work. What should I do to get these formulas back?
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/boost-python.rb
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/boost.rb

Comment: You generally don't need to `tap` formulae in homebrew-core. You can just install it as `brew install boost-python`.

Comment: @EliSadoff Hey thanks for your answer. But I just `rm` the formula from the disk and brew can never find the `boost-python`

Comment: `brew install boost-python` works for me. What do you get when you run that command?

Comment: It should work for me you know... But what I just did is delete the `boost-python` formula from my disk. So when I tap `brew install boost-python` it gives me `not found formula`.

Comment: @EliSadoff I think I just figured out how to fix it, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
brew update-reset
```

> The update-reset version of this command resets all formulae to be identical to the contents of their remote repositories, deleting any local changes. It is only used as a last-resort effort to fix a problem (it’s like unplugging Homebrew and plugging it back in).

Answer (score 1):

The way to fix it is directly installing a formula from Github:

`brew install https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/boost-python.rb`