# How to get back Homebrew to previous state?

Tags: macos, cassandra, homebrew

I deleted some of **.rb files(cassandra.rb,cassandra@2.1.rb and cassandra@2.2.rb)** from folder `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/` from mac system.I want back those .rb files.
I thought `brew upgrade` will give me back those deleted .rb files back.But they are still missing. Those .rb files are important for me to install packages.

`brew install cassandra` gives

```
Updating Homebrew...
Error: No available formula with the name "cassandra" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula...
cassandra was deleted from homebrew/core in commit d20fe73:
  cassandra: update 3.10_1 bottle.

To show the formula before removal run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" show d20fe73^:Formula/cassandra.rb

If you still use this formula consider creating your own tap:
  http://docs.brew.sh/How-to-Create-and-Maintain-a-Tap.html
```

Please I need solution **"how to get back these .rb files?"** or **"any other alternative way to install cassandra"**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restore brew formula after I rm it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40847507/how-to-restore-brew-formula-after-i-rm-it)

Answer (score 2):

Install directly from GitHub as mentioned here -
[How to restore brew formula after I rm it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40847507/how-to-restore-brew-formula-after-i-rm-it)

```
brew install https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/tree/master/Formula/cassandra.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this command to bring back all of deleted files.
Note: This command will revert all change in `$(brew --repo homebrew/core)`

```
cd $(brew --repo homebrew/core) && git reset --hard origin/master
```

Homebrew uses git internally, so use git commands to repair some problem.